# How to enable the Rails cache for a single cucumber scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, cucumber, cache-control

I've written a cron job to update some cached values in the background (rather than doing it while a user waits). I have a scenario that runs that cron job and then reads the cache to see if the values are set correctly.

The problem is that `Rails.cache.read("key")` is returning `"Cache read: key\n"` not the value, and if I debug and inspect `Rails.cache` I get a `ActiveSupport::Cache::BlackHoleStore` returned - not a good sign.

This makes sense of course because the following is included in my `cucumber.env`:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching             = false
require File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'lib', 'black_hole_store.rb')
config.cache_store = :black_hole_store
```

What I want is to override this at runtime - we have about a thousand scenarios and this is the only one that needs the cache active. I tried the following from the debugger prompt without any luck:

```
(rdb:1) ActionController::Base.perform_caching = true
true
(rdb:1) ActionController::Base.perform_caching
true
(rdb:1) Rails.cache
#<ActiveSupport::Cache::BlackHoleStore:0x101b6dc60 @logger_off=false>
(rdb:1) ActionController::Base.cache_store = :memory_store
:memory_store
(rdb:1) Rails.cache
#<ActiveSupport::Cache::BlackHoleStore:0x101b6dc60 @logger_off=false>
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this...tag your scenarios with `@enable_caching` and add these hooks to your `support/env.rb` file:

```
Before '@enable_caching' do
  ActionController::Base.perform_caching = true
end

After '@enable_caching' do
  ActionController::Base.perform_caching = false
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I eventually got to the bottom of this.

The short answer is `Rails.cache` is an alias for `RAILS_CACHE`, and while there's no `Rails.cache=` method you can assign to `RAILS_CACHE`, e.g.:

```
ActionController::Base.perform_caching = true
ActionController::Base.cache_store = :memory_store
RAILS_CACHE = ActionController::Base.cache_store
```

You could probably also do `RAILS_CACHE = ActiveSupport::Cache.lookup_store(:memory_cache)` but that seems a bit dirtier to me.

The longer answer is to use a step to wrap a table of other steps with code that enables and then disables the cache, to ensure you don't break other tests by leaving caching enabled - this kind of mistake is nasty to track down.

This would look something like:

```
When /^I do the following steps with caching enabled:$/ do |table|
  old_perform_caching = ActionController::Base.perform_caching
  old_action_controller_cache = ActionController::Base.cache_store
  old_rails_cache = RAILS_CACHE

  ActionController::Base.perform_caching = true
  ActionController::Base.cache_store = :memory_store
  RAILS_CACHE = ActionController::Base.cache_store

  steps table.raw.flatten.join("\n")

  ActionController::Base.perform_caching = old_perform_caching
  ActionController::Base.cache_store = old_action_controller_cache
  RAILS_CACHE = old_rails_cache
end
```

And using it would look something like:

```
 When I do the following steps with caching enabled:            
 | When I run "rake cron:nightly"             |
 | Then the cache for "x" should return "6"   |
 |  And the cache for "y" should return "13"  |
 |  And the cache for "z" should return "800" |
```

The steps in the table have obviously been implemented elsewhere.

Comment: An alternative would be to tag the scenario(s) you want to run with the cache with @cache. You could then implement the logic to enable the cache before the scenarios and disable it afterwards in you env.rb file in a before block and an after block.

Answer (score 0):

This seems kind of related to my question/anser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810289/setting-the-cache-store-in-an-initializer). The issue is that you can't change cache_store after Rails is initialized. There's a cache initializer that gets run during Rails initialization. As far as I'm aware, you can't change it after it's initialized. Perhaps you can mock the cache read/write?