# Heroku Rails 3 Rails.cache.class reports ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore after I call Rails.application.config.cache_store = :redis_store, "#{url}"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, redis

Where `url=redis://redistogo:XXXYYYZZZ@cod.redistogo.com:9362/`

This is called in my initializer code.

Here is the other pertinent config options:

1) in production.rb

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true in my production.rb
```

2) In my controller:

```
caches_action :show, :layout => false, :if => Proc.new {|c| c.request.query_string.blank?}  
caches_page :get_session_info
```

3) in the initializer:

```
Rails.application.config.cache_store = :redis_store, "#{url}"
```

PS: I checked this by running a production console from my local machine. I actually re-ran the call to `cache_store` followed by `Rails.cache.class`. I ALSO ran the console from the `heroku run bash` shell (on an actual Heroku dyno) with the same results.

PPS: I think I want to switch to use memcached

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the cache\_store in an initializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810289/setting-the-cache-store-in-an-initializer)